# Hiding Excel Ribbon using VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, excel, ribbon

I'm wondering if it's possible to remove all menu items 
except for the minimize button.  I'm wanting to use Excel as a help screen that the user 
only views and minimizes, nothing else. I want only my one excel 
file to have the new ribbon.

I've tried to hide the Excel ribbon using

```
xlapp.ExecuteExcel4Macro("SHOW.TOOLBAR(""Ribbon"",False)")
xlapp.Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Enabled = False
```

and also sendkeys as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735595/remove-ribbon-from-excel).

Is this possible with [ribbon editor](http://www.andypope.info/vba/ribboneditor.htm)?  I couldn't 
make menu items delete.  Also when completed, is the ribbon unique to the worksheet, or 
does the excel application always utilize the new ribbon?

Comment: Consider using an [HTA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the help screen. Write your content in HTML and you can also customize the appearance of the window very easily - remove right-click menu, no title bar, no minimize buttons etc.

Comment: but my Excel sheet has text, formulas formatting all completed.  And when excel items are updated and changed, Excel help screen will reflect changes already with no updating needed.